# Что из себя представляет значение объекта класса java.util.Date в кафка-сообщении?

Tags: java, сериализация, apache-kafka

Мой сервис отсылает сообщение в формате DTO с разными типами полей - *String*, *Integer*, *Date* итд. *Kafka producer* сериализует это DTO, kafka consumer в другом сервисе десериализует. Через *KafkaTool* я могу посмотреть журнал конкретного топика со своим содержимым. 
В своём сообщении в поле *content* я увидел, что строковые и числовые типы данных отображаются корректно, но объекты типа *Date* представляют собой последовательность чисел. Например, как на скриншоте.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Причем, когда *Kafka Listener* в другом сервисе десериализует сообщение, то я получаю корректное значение *Date*.
Я так понимаю в *KafkaTool* нет конкретного десериализатора и он отображает байтовое представление?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для сериализации даты, по умолчанию, используется числовой формат [Unix-time](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F).

Unix-time хранит количество миллисекунд, прошедшее с полуночи (00:00:00) 1 января 1970 года (с момента "Unix Epoch").

Стоит заметить, что `java.util.Date` также хранит данные аналогичным образом, предоставляя соответствующий конструктор и методы:

```
Date date = new Date(1541538000000L);
date.getTime();   // 1541538000000L
date.toString();  // Wed Nov 07 00:00:00 MSK 2018
```

---

**Примечания:**

Очевидно, что в рамках данного формата хранения данных, если сериализуемый в рамках даты момент времени был до 1970 года, то число будет отрицательным.

Также, очевидно, что при использовании такого формата хранения имеются ограничения снизу и сверху, накладываемое используемым форматом хранения количества миллисекунд: в рамках java используется 64 битный `long`.

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy G HH:mm:ss Z");

// вс, 2 дек. 292269055 до н. э. 19:47:04 +0300
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(new Date(Long.MIN_VALUE)));

// вс, 17 авг. 292278994 н. э. 10:12:55 +0300
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(new Date(Long.MAX_VALUE)));
```

---

**Поправка:**

В оригинальном формате Unix-time имеются некоторые отличия от используемого в рамках стека Java и Kafka (которые были описаны выше):

1. хранится количество секунд (а не миллисекунд), прошедших с момента "Unix Epoch" (`01.01.1970`);
2. для хранения данных используется 32-битный (а не 64-битный) тип данных (если проводить аналогию с java - `int`).

Данные особенности накладывали бы совсем другие границы временных значений на оригинальный формат Unix-time: удалось бы закодировать лишь интервал в 136 лет (с `1901.12.13` до `2038.01.19`).